# Changing domains, redirecting sub-directories

Tags: redirect, cross-domain

My client is changing his domain, and I'm curious about the best way to make all the existing links on other sites work, so that:

- www.olddomain.com/page1.html
- www.olddomain.com/other-section/page2.html

redirect automatically to:

- www.newdomain.com/page1.html
- www.newdomain.com/other-section/page2.html

Is there a way to set it up so that all the old links simply correspond to the exact same structure, simply with a new domain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge you would have to keep the old domain and redirect from there with '301's in an .htaccess file or something similar.

An example .htaccess file might look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Or:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 /dir/ http://www.newdomain.com/dir/
Redirect 301 /dir/file.html http://www.newdomain.com/dir/file.html
```

I suggest you read up on [301 Redirects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) and [.htaccess files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess). This [.htaccess generator](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/) might also be of use to you.

Comment: Thanks so much. Ideally I'd love to find a way to do this without keeping the old domain active--especially because I've heard that Google dings you for having replicated, identical content, but more importantly because that would mean maintaining two pages for every page in the site (~50 pages). I'll read up--thank you!

Comment: Actually, if you 301 redirect the old domain google will only index the new domain. So even if you leave the content there, it would not count as duplicate content. That said, you can delete the old content... you really only need the domain to park the .htaccess file.